# getting error using jenkins pipe line

Tags: jenkins

when i'm trying to copy using jenkins pipe job,getting beloe error. what was the exact issue?

```
Started by user balajinew
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copyjob
[copyjob] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins8729334247736026943.sh
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ec2-user/jenkins-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar’: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Kindly format your question so it is readable.

Comment: Show us your pipeline code please.